# bootstrap-select.js slow performance to render with hugh dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap-select.js and my option size is more than 5,000. The problem comes when I select an element from the list. The click event renders all the <li> get the tabindex and internally assigns option with the same index as true or false. This takes a huge amount of time, is there any way I can reduce the time for browser to respond? or any other suggestions.

-Thanks

Comment: There is no code in your question. This means nobody can help you.